# Is there a way to write single backslash within lists?

Tags: python, python-3.8

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4sRA.png)
is there a way to print single backslash within list?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score -1):

Regarding the first version of your question, I wrote this:

1. First, this expression `x='\'` isn't right in Python in python. you should rather puth it this way: `x='\\'`, since back slash is a special character in python.
2. Second, try this:

> `l=['\\'] print(l)`
> This will print: `['\\']`

> But when you execute this: `print(l[0])`, it renders this `'\'`. So basically, this `['\\']` is the way to print a backslash within a list.